# How to prevent elements from overlapping in CSS?

Tags: html, css, htmlelements

I'm new to CSS and I am trying to make a website. I have created my navbar at the top but when I change the height of my browser, the content of block `<h1>` wrapped in a textbox starts to overlap the navbar at one point.
How can I prevent it? I want to keep the text in the middle of the background image at all times when resizing the window. Thanks in advance.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(75, 54, 33, 0.7), rgba(75, 54, 33, 0.7)), url(../img/coffee_beans.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #382512;
  height: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 99999;
}

nav img {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  /*background-color: #382512;*/
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #d66717;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text-box {
  width: 90%;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.text-box p {
  margin: 25px 0 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.learnmore-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.learnmore-btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #d66717;
  background: #d66717;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="header">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"></a>
      <div class="nav-links" id="menuLinks">
        <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Strona Główna</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Parzenie Kawy</a></li>
          <li><a href="">O Ziarnach Kawy</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-box">
      <h1>Poszerz swoje kawowe horyzonty i spraw aby każdy kubek kawy był niezapomniany !</h1>
      <p>Nasz serwis jest poświęcony wszystkiemu co związane z kawą, dowiesz się czym charakteryzują się kawy z różnych regionów, nauczysz sie więcej o metodach parzenia i nie tylko !<br> Dzięki zdobytej wiedzy sprawisz że każdy kubek twojej kawy będzie4
        idealny !</p>
      <a href="" class="learnmore-btn">Dowiedz się więcej</a>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using absolute positioning unless you really know why. It doesn't seem necessary here, and obviously it causes problems (especially in a flex layout).

Comment: I took a look, but you have a few problems so I'm not sure what your goal is. My advice is to start over with the layout CSS, working from outside inward, and just do one step at a time.

Comment: I wanted to keep the text from .text-box at the center of background image at all times when resizing the browser window. I tried different ways ex. i made .header a flex container and used different aligning (center for .text-box and flex-start for nav) but the text kept floating out to the left and it wasnt seen fully. So for now using absolute positioning seemed to work the way i wanted to the only drawback is the overlapping